# Xcode localisation for iOS - difference between French (fr) and French Belgium (fr-BE)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm currently in the process of localising my iOS application. When I go to my project, under the localisation menu when I click the + button, I get a list of languages to pick from, for example French (fr). Also, at the bottom of that menu there is a sub menu titled "other", that menu has loads more languages to pick from, but they are all like French Belgium (fr-BE) and English Canada (en-CA). Can someone please explain how this works and what the difference is between French (fr) and French Belgium (fr-BE) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a locale string, the first two letters describe the *language*, the second two letters describe the *region*.

The same language may be spoken differently in different regions. I'll assume from your username that you are most familiar with the English language. In English, there are significant differences between the same language as used in different regions. Some of those are:

- vocabulary: in en-GB "boot" is the storage room in the back of your car, in en-US, it's something you put on your foot, the car thing is called "trunk"; in en-GB, "football" is a sport where you play a ball with your foot, in en-US, it's a sport where you play an egg with your hand.
- spelling: color–colour, favorite–favourite, program–programme, …
- pronunciation: in en-GB, aluminium is pronounced aluminium, in en-US, it's pronounced aluminum.

Localization is also about much more than just the language. It's also about currency (pound vs. dollar), date formats, number formatting, phone number formatting, address formatting, collation, etc. All of those depend much more on the region than on the language. In fact, in regions with multiple languages (e.g. Switzerland, Belgium), they will usually be the same across languages.

Now, since you asked specifically about Belgium: Belgium is a tri-lingual country, and even though there is a sharp divide between the three regions, the languages influence each other. So, the French spoken and written in Belgium is heavily influenced mostly by the Dutch spoken and written in Belgium, which the French spoken in France isn't. The French spoken in Canada, because of the great distance to France, has developed independently of it, and is in some ways closer to what was spoken in Revolutionary France than today. Ergo, it makes sense to distinguish French as spoken in Canada, France, Belgium both from each other as well from "French in general".

Answer (score 0):

They are different versions of French. The English you hear in the UK is different from the one you hear in USA or in Canada. Apple gives you the possibility to be as precise as possible with localizing a language.